# Rails 3.1: How do i add an initializer that runs after gem initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

My scaffold generator stopped working after we updated factory girl.  Here's why happened.  First, my config file tries to set up certain defaults for scaffold generation, like so:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.app_generators do |g|
    g.template_engine     'mizugumo:haml'
    g.scaffold_controller 'mizugumo:scaffold_controller'
    g.assets              'mizugumo:js_assets'
    g.test_framework      :lrdspec, :fixture => true
    g.fixture_replacement 'lrdspec:factory'

    g.fallbacks['mizugumo:haml']  = :haml
    g.fallbacks[:lrdspec] = :rspec
  end
  ...
end
```

Where :lrdspec is the name of my company's scaffold spec generator.  However, the most recent factory_girl_rails, in its initializer, rudely **forces config.generators.test_framework to 'test_unit'** unless your test framework is exactly ":rspec":

```
module FactoryGirl
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie

  initializer "factory_girl.set_fixture_replacement" do
    generators = config.respond_to?(:app_generators) ? config.app_generators : config.generators

    if generators.options[:rails][:test_framework] == :rspec
      generators.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, :dir => 'spec/factories'
    else
      generators.test_framework :test_unit, :fixture => false, :fixture_replacement => :factory_girl
    end
  end
```

What I am trying to figure out how to do, is to generate my own initializer that runs after FG's initializer, to set test_framework back to :lrdspec, as I want it.

I've tried dropping my own railtie into config/initializers, or adding a block to config.after_initialize in config/application.rb, and a number of other approaches, but  haven't quite found the solution.   (My knowledge of Rails' initialization sequence needs to be a bit deeper than it is' I think).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html (or http://railsguts.com/initialization.html for Rails 2)?

Comment: Yeah .. that (and the code of railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb are what I've been reading for the past couple of hours.   They're helpful, but I can't see (from either source) see how to affect the *order* of initializers that are created.

Comment: Initializers (e.g. config/initializers/foobar.rb) are loaded in "alphabetical" order. Should be pretty easy to find the line of code that does the actual grepping for files, no?

Answer (score 3):

Okay - found a solution.  Sometimes just posting a question can help in thinking it through.

The answer was to set my own initializer in the gem that holds my scaffold generator, and to pass :after => "factory_girl.set_fixture_replacement" to initialize() when I create that block.   The fact that you can specify :after to the initializer isn't documented in the Rails docco, but can be deduced by discovering that Initializable uses TSort to sort its collection of initializers, researching how TSort works, and discovering that the stored :after/:before parameters are used in the methods that TSort calls back to.

So the fix was to drop this in the configuration Railtie for my own gem, the one that provides the scaffold generator:

```
initializer "lrd_dev_tools.set_generators", :after => 'factory_girl.set_fixture_replacement' do
  generators = config.respond_to?(:app_generators) ? config.app_generators : config.generators
  generators.test_framework :lrdspec, :fixture => true
  generators.fixture_replacement 'lrdspec:factory'      
end
```